# change points/break points in nonlinear regression

Tags: estimation, nonlinear, change-point

I have a problem in which I am trying to estimate change/break points where the data has a linear portion (or semi-linear at least)and a nonlinear (actually an exponential) portion. Does anyone know how to do this? To make matters worse, the dataset has only 7 datapoints. However, when you view it, there is an obvious single breakpoint. Ideas?

Comment: Can you paste an example of possible dataset?

Comment: 0 1.00 86648.03
18 1.75 101912.00
24 2.00 114349.81
42 2.75 143267.10
48 3.00 147048.69
66 3.75 400687.43
72 4.00 524333.43

Comment: Ignore the second column in the dataset just use columns 1 and 3

Comment: Ok, I have an idea, I'll try and let you know if it works

Comment: Sounds fantastic.

Comment: Conversely to other optimistic comments, a linear and an exponential segment plus a breakpoint sounds like about 5 parameters to estimate from 7 data points!

Comment: I agree. But that's the data. And when you plot some of the data sets and do a segmental analysis by eyeball, it is definitely a linear followed by exponential with high r2 and very small p-values.

Answer (score 1):

I imagined a way to solve your problem and did a small research on it, which I'm sharing below. I don't think that it actually directly achieves what you're aiming at, but I hope you'll find it useful.

Your time series was normalized to simplify fitting procedures.

---

### Exponential non-linearity window detection in time series

1. To detect a part of time series which exhibits exponential behavior, we break it in small regions, defined by sizes:

   $SizeWindows = [s_1;s_2]$, where $2<s_1<s_2<N-s_1+1$, and $N$ is the size of time series
2. To each small region we fit an exponential ($y = A e^{-Bx} + C$) and linear curve, calculating the Root-Mean-Square error for both of them.
3. By comparing RMSE values, we determine if a region of specific size at specific data starting point exhibits exponential non-linear behavior. (In other words, we determine if the least-square fit was better for exponential curve).

---

### Interpolation

Since there are only 7 points in the given time series, only window sizes $[3;6]$ are allowed.

Since fitting of 3-point region with an exponent is problematic, we interpolate the given time series as a semi-linear, quadratic or cubic function.

As a result we are able to use more points for fitting purposes

---

### Results

Linear interpolation

[image]

Quadratic interpolation

[image]

Cubic interpolation

[image]

---

### Interpretation

Following from the results, my impression is that **7 data points are not enough to detect with confidence a window which exhibits exponential behavior**, because the result depends a lot on the interpolation/resampling method and **there are simply not enough data points** if we avoid interpolation.

This looks pretty obvious now, but it did not initially. :)

In this context promising for your actual aim looks to me the next approach.

**Examine as many of data samples as possible and look for a way to detect 'breakpoints' as peaks based on values of mean and standard deviation, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22640362/5908572) answer.**

---

All code available [here](https://gist.github.com/0x0af/043249ba2a1cba70e52e#file-breakpoints) in python. Feel free to try or modify it yourself!